# XNextEvent() in Rust segfaults

Tags: rust, segmentation-fault, x11, xlib

A couple months ago, I started writing an X11 window manager in C with Xlib and I'm now trying to rewrite it in Rust. (after all, rust is the future, right?)

This is the code from [main.rs](https://github.com/ChromaCat248/zwin/blob/main/src/main.rs) that segfaults:

```
    // event loop
    loop {
        let mut event : *mut XEvent = 0 as *mut XEvent;
        unsafe {
            XNextEvent(DISPLAY, event);
            /*match (*event).type_ {
                CreateNotify => {
                    println!("sdfg");
                }
                _ => {
                    println!("sdfgsdfg");
                }
            }*/
        }
        println!("dsfgsdfg");
    }
```

Using GDB, I was able to narrow it down to XNextEvent inside the unsafe block. I'm not really sure where to go from there, since it's calling a function /use/lib/libX11.so.6 and I can't list the function to see where it quit.

Before you ask about the unsafe block, I can't put Xlib functions outside of unsafe blocks because they are unsafe functions and the compiler will complain.

The project uses the `x11` crate on crates.io.

Comment: You're passing a `NULL` pointer to `XNextEvent`'s `event_return` parameter, so your program crashes when `XNextEvent` tries to write there.

Comment: @Jmb: Just as if you wrote in C: `XEvent *event = 0; XNextEvent(DISPLAY, event);` it will surely crash, too.

Comment: the future would be to use wayland no ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing a pointer to `NULL` instead of a pointer to a local variable to be filled by `XNextEvent`, just as if your C code did:

```
XEvent *event = NULL;
XNextEvent(DISPLAY, event); //crash!
```

In C, you are probably doing:

```
XEvent event;
XNextEvent(DISPLAY, &event);
```

But unfortunately you cannot do that directly in Rust because you cannot declare an uninitialized variable:

```rust
let mut event: XEvent;
XNextEvent(DISPLAY, &mut event); //error: event is not initialized
```

If `XEvent` implemented `Default` you could just default initialize it, but I think [it does not](https://docs.rs/x11/2.18.2/x11/xlib/union.XEvent.html).

For these cases you can use [`MaybeUninit`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html):

```rust
let event = unsafe {
    let mut event = MaybeUninit::uninit();
    XNextEvent(DISPLAY, event.as_mut_ptr());
    event.assume_init()
};
```

Comment: @Stargateur: About that edit, I thought of something like that, but `man 3 XNextEvent`  says nothing about the return value, it is as if this function cannot fail... and looking at the source code, it [looks like it always returns `0`](https://github.com/mirror/libX11/blob/5faa8dc0b364f55f19034c370436074646d9ad54/src/NextEvent.c#L38).

Comment: That makes a lot of sense that it's trying to write to a memory address that doesn't contain an XEvent. What I don't understand is that since I declared event outside of the unsafe block, shouldn't rustc disallow assigning a null pointer to it?

Comment: @ChromaCat248: Outside `unsafe` you can create the `MaybeUninit` and get a pointer to it, but you cannot call the native function nor convert it to a real `XEvent`. Those are the real dangerous operations, and for those you need `unsafe`.

Comment: @rodrigo don't look implementation detail that very bad thing to do, one implementation could have no error but another could, another source clearly say no error == 0 https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/man/man3/XDisplayMotionBufferSize.3.xhtml better safe than sorry. if the function is expect to never fail it's would return `void` not `int`

Comment: @Stargateur: But you are linking the man of `XSendEvent`, not `XNextEvent`. The linked `XNextEvent` inside your page says just the same as my `man` page: nothing. I've looked at other bindings and other uses and it looks like a consensus that `XNextEvent` cannot fail. More over, even if it failed, it is not clear whether it should return `1` (one event copied) or `0 ` (no error).

Comment: @rodrigo mm indeed anyway my first source I put it in the edit comment,; https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/libX11/specs/libX11/libX11.html#Errors clearly say 0 == no error by default. and again, assuming is bad. the function design allow to return error, user should handle it. Recently in Rust we try to introduce OOM handling, people assume write never fail for Vec despite write returning an error, and now we have problem, that annoying to look at implementation behavior and assume it will never error. Than user cry about it.

Comment: @Stargateur: The reference you link is for functions returning `Status`, this one returns `int`. And look at the source: libX11 will return `0` always, so in any case it should be `0` equals no error. I think that this is just a relic from when C did not have a `void` type. If the documentation does not say what the return value means, my understanding is that it means nothing. Giving it a meaning that the documentation does not say is just what you say (rightly) you should not do: guessing.

Comment: "you should not do: guessing." that literally what you are doing here. on the contrary I don't, there is an int, the doc say 0 == no error, no detail in the doc of the function. You assume it's never error, I assume nothing and follow documentation. You are doing the worst thing ever, look implementation detail.

Comment: but you have a point maybe only function that return `Status` can fail, but the documentation is totally unclear. Several function return `void` so I still think the `int` should be handle. I want to again share that x11 is the worst thing ever created.

Comment: @Stargateur: "but the documentation is totally unclear" in that we agree ;-). Anyway, 0 cannot mean error because the actual implementation returns always 0, and it certainly works. And any [source](https://github.com/coapp-packages/gtk/blob/master/gdk/x11/gdkevents-x11.c#L2289) I [found](https://github.com/openwebos/qt/blob/master/src/gui/kernel/qguieventdispatcher_glib.cpp#L103) just ignores this return value. So I you don't mind I'll just revert the edit.

Comment: @ChromaCat248 Assigning `NULL` (or any other value) to a pointer is always safe. The only unsafe operation with pointers is dereferencing them. This is why the compiler doesn't complain with your original code.